# json object referencing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete, jsonp

I have the following list of search terms in JSON:

http://completion.amazon.com/search/complete?method=completion&q=halo&search-alias=aps&mkt=1

```
[ "halo",
  [ "halo reach",
    "halo anniversary",
    "halo 4",
    "halo 3",
    "halo mega bloks",
    "halo 2",
    "halo sleepsack",
    "halo wars",
    "halo reach xbox 360",
    "halo combat evolved"
  ],
  [ { "nodes" : [
        { "name"  : "Video Games",
          "alias" : "videogames"
        }
      ]
    },
    {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}
  ],
  []
]
```

I am using jQuery to return the results in an autocomplete.

My question is, how would I reference the categories (nodes) in the object? I can reference the terms in the first part like so:

```
var myQuery = "harry"
  , myCount = 0
;

$.ajax({
  url       : "http://completion.amazon.com/search/complete",
  type      : "GET",
  cache     : false,
  dataType  : "jsonp",
  success   : function (data) {
    $(data[1]).each(function(index) {
        alert(data[1][myCount]);
        myCount++;
      }
    );
  },
  data      : {
    q               : myQuery,
    "search-alias"  : "aps",
    mkt             : "1",
    callback        : '?'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(data[2][0].nodes).each(function () { alert(this.name) })`

**Edit:** Fixed by question author. :)

Comment: @Nick `$(data[2].nodes).each(function () { alert(this.name) })`

Comment: @DanielBrockman thanks for the reply. I cant seem to get that to return anything  (i am adding it to the success part).

Comment: sussed it            $.each(data[2][0].nodes, function(i, res) {
              res.name
              }